# Getting the list of files in website's folder through terminal

Tags: command-line, terminal, apache2, server

I've configured Apache2 for a specific directory, so that it lists all its contents over HTTP (I put `+Indexes`in config).

I was wondering if it is possible to list the contents of that folder from my terminal? So basically instead of opening up a browser and visiting that directory over HTTP, is it possible to do it just from terminal?

Comment: try `curl` or `wget` or `lynx -dump` and so on.

Comment: I tried `wget` and it works. But now I have another question. If I put index.html file in that directory, can I still get the list of contents anyhow?

Comment: No. The directory index is provided because there was no index.html file. You'll need to work harder to have them both.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas:

- use `ssh` to connect to the webserver: `ssh user@host ls /path/to/dir`; requires `ssh` access obviously
- add a `cgi` script to generate the output you want in a format (test/plain) you want